# standby only at login screen?

Tags: windows-7

I have 10 computers running Windows 7 connected to Active Directory.  I would like to setup the computers so that they go into standby if no one logs in for 15 minutes, BUT I want the computers NOT to go into standby ever if someone is logged in.

This would involve the changing of Power Plans.  Is there a way to have one Power Plan loaded when the computer is not logged in and a different Power Plan loaded when a user is logged in?

**UPDATE**: Using jscott's suggestions I think I have what I want working. I made a Power Plan called Logged_In for the User Configuration and Logged_Out for the Computer Configuration.  The last glitch I had to fix was that Logged_In was applied after logout until the next policy refresh.  I made the following script to run at logout based on code I found >[here](http://mikecel79.wordpress.com/2011/08/)<:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWshScriptExec = objShell.exec("powercfg.exe -list")
Set objStdOut = objWshScriptExec.stdOut

While Not objStdOut.AtEndOfStream
   strLine = objStdOut.ReadLine
   If InStr(strLine,"Logged_Out") Then
      strGuid = Mid(strLine,20,37)
   End If   
Wend
objShell.run "powercfg.exe -setactive " & strGuid
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to create a GPO.  You'll want to look under Computer Configuration, Preferences, Control Panel Settings, Power Option.  Then right click and select New, Power Plan.  From there you can specify all the power settings you want.  Here is a technet article.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759141.aspx

Comment: But how do you automate the changing of the Power Plan?

Comment: @Joseph - Via group policy.

Comment: @joseph Assign a computer configuration Power Plan for the computer settings. Assign a user configuration Power Plan for the user settings.  When nobody is logged in, the Computer Power Plan will be used.

Comment: @jscott How do you change it back to the Computer Configuration after a user has logged out?

Comment: @Joseph Both the computer and user will have their own Power Plans -- that is you configure one under Computer Configuration, the other under User Configuration. When a user is logged on, the User Configuration GP settings are active. When a user logs off, the User Configuration settings will fall out-of-scope and the Computer Configuration GP will be the active settings.

Comment: @jscott How long does that usually take? The Computer Configuration Power Plan works perfectly on bootup if a Group Policy update was applied and the User Configuration Power Plan works perfectly on logon, but the computer is not switching to the Computer Configuration after logoff or reboot until the Group Policy is applied again.

Comment: @Joseph [It depends](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757597(WS.10).aspx). You can reduce the refresh time if you don't want the computer to have to wait for the default refresh to come around and update the Power Plan.

Comment: @jscott Make your comment into an answer, and I'll give you the points. I've made a logout script that might fix my last issue which I will post when I've confirmed it works.